# Release Android key for Google Map api not working

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I get a release android key, which is a Release certificate(SHA-1 fingerprin), but it is till not working for my release.apk, the debug key(Debug certificate) works fine. I don't know why, does anyone know? Please help!

Comment: please paste logs of the signing/zip-aligning process for us to take a look at.

Answer (score 1):

Just check your google_maps_key under the src/release directory, you should place there your own key from the google console (the one you got with the release fingerprint SHA1).

This happens because the default google_maps_key file you access is the one of the debug, so the release key will never notice this, you must place it on your release version of google_maps_key.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a debug key for a release.apk, you need a release key for publish you apk!

Read this documment, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key
and you will find you answers!

Good Luck!

Comment: Yes, I did use a release key for publishing, but the map is not showing if you download it from Google Playhttps://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lchen.luyaochen.map

Answer (score 0):

1- Create apk file using "Use the export Wizard" in "Android Manifest" file of your project.

2- After inserting key and before finishing, MD5 and SHA1 keys are shown as shown is this [given pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SldEv.png)-

3- Create new API Key for Android project for new SHA1 which is retrieved in point 2.

4- Use that API key in manifest file as shown below

5- Clean your project and build APK file again.

6- You can see google maps now in that apk.